# No items are displayed on recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, rx-java

I am getting data from an api and showing it on a recyclerview. I have checked many other queries of the same issue but i cant seem to find a way to solve this.

Below is my activity class

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val retrofit = RetrofitClient.instance
    jsonApi = retrofit.create(MyApi::class.java)

    fetchRecyclerData()

}

private fun fetchRecyclerData() {
    compositeDisposable?.add(jsonApi.posts
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe{posts->displayData(posts)})

}

private fun displayData(posts: List<Post>?) {
    val adapter = PostAdapter(this,posts!!)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

}
}
```

Below is my adapter

```
class PostAdapter(internal var context: Context, internal var 
postList:List<Post>):RecyclerView.Adapter<PostViewHolder>()
{

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PostViewHolder {
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.post_layout,parent,false)
    return PostViewHolder(itemView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PostViewHolder, position: Int) {
   holder.tvAuthor.text = postList[position].userId.toString()
    holder.tvContent.text = StringBuilder(postList[position].body.substring(0,20))
        .append("...").toString()
    holder.tvTitle.text = postList[position].title
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return postList.size
}
}
```

Logcat

```
     06-17 13:29:06.047 23952-23952/com.malikali.kotlinxrxjava2xretrofit2 W/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
     06-17 13:29:06.057 23952-23952/com.malikali.kotlinxrxjava2xretrofit2 W/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

Below is my xml file. I still don't understand what am doing wrong in this case.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on adapter after submitting data so change your code like this:

```
private fun displayData(posts: List<Post>?) {
    val adapter = PostAdapter(this,posts!!)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()


}
```

Comment: @Mkhapaki i had tried that i just forgot to include that in the code. It still doesn't show

Answer (score 0):

Please also share your xml. three possible conditions
1: the recycler view must be of 0 height or width
2: 'posts' list is empty
3: make logs in the subscribe to see if not throwing any exception else implement error of rxjava to check for possible exceptions